# Pass value to vuex store from mapActions in component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

How would I access the value inside my @click partSelect from my Vuex store.

Vue Template

```
<div id="currentPart">
    <img id="modelImg" @click="partSelect('modelOne')" class="modelImg" :src="model[0]"/>
    <img id="modelImg2" @click="partSelect('modelTwo')" class="modelImg" :src="model[1]"/>
    <img id="modelImg3" @click="partSelect('modelThree')" class="modelImg" :src="model[2]"/>
  </div>
```

Javascript to map actions

```
<script> 
 methods: mapActions([
    'getImage',
    'getImageAsync',
    'partSelect'
  ]),
</script>
```

Vuex Javascript

```
export const partSelect = ({ commit }) => commit('partSelect')
```

Comment: Can you show me the partSelected action definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple, the action in Vuex should look like this:

```
export const partSelect = ({ commit }, myString) => {
    // do something with myString
    commit('partSelectMutation') // execute the mutation
    // if the data should be added to the mutation:
    // commit('partSelectMutation', { myString })
}
```

to access the variable myString in the mutation (if the second version above was used):

```
mutations: {
    partSelectMutation: (state, { myString }) => {
         state.myString = myString
    },
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you I forgot to save my updates to the code adding the string. Your solution works well! One other clarification if you would though. How would I access the string from my mutation if i add the // commit('partSelect', { myString })

Comment: `export const partSelect = state => {
  console.log(myString)
  if (state.frameNum >= 1) {
    state.frameNum = 0
  } else {
    state.frameNum++
  }
}`

Comment: I've updated my answer, feel free to ask if something is unclear. I have not tested the code though, I just copied and modified this snippet from my own code.

Answer (score 1):

Simple example with mapped action as event callback:

```js
var store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    content: 'Old content'
  },
  mutations: {
    updateContent (state, payload) {
      state.content = payload
    }
  },
  actions: {
    mapMe (context, payload) {
      context.commit('updateContent', payload)
    }
  }
})

new Vue ({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  computed: {
    content () {
      return this.$store.state.content
    }
  },
  methods: Vuex.mapActions({
    mappedAction: 'mapMe'
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  {{ content }}<br>
  <button @click="mappedAction('New content')">Click</button>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
const mutations = {
    myrequest (state, id) {
        console.log("id:" + id);
    }
}    
const actions = {
    myrequest ({ commit }, id) {
        commit('myrequest', id)
    }
}
```